# Hamiltonian Path with restrictions

Tags: np-complete

I'm trying to solve the hamiltonian path problem but with restrictions.
What sort of restrictions? Each vertex has a value, and if the value is i, than I want the hemiltonian path to include this vertex on it's i'th place on the path.
For example, I want the vertex marked as $5$ to be the 5'th in the path.
The vertex marked as $10$ to be the 10'th in the path.

I'm looking for an easy way to solve this, I couldn't find any algorithms or information about this.

Thanks,
Tal

Comment: As it is, this question lacks context. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question for information on how to attract quality answers.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I tried to edit it and hope that now it is more clear...